# Measure LiPo / Li-Ion SOC or the ever standing question of how much juice is remaining in my battery?

Tags: battery, software

So I have a project in which an arduino runs on a two cell LiPo battery and I need a fast, straight forward way to determine remaining battery charge (with an accuracy of 10% so I only have a readout with 10 LEDs on it) without using any major extra components (so using an external battery charge meter IC is cheating :P). How should I go about this?

(using arduino mini, LiPo is two cells: 7,4V 150mAh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a low-leakage op amp to divide the battery voltage by 8 (A<sub>V</sub> of 1/8). Connect the output to an analog input. Set your reference to the internal 1.1V reference ([`INTERNAL`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference)). Perform analog reads. Full battery will be about 975 ((8.4V/8)/1.1V⋅1024 ~= 977.45455). Empty will be about 700 ((6.0V/8)/1.1V⋅1024 ~= 698.18182). Note that the voltage scaling for Li-ion cells is non-linear; see the datasheet for the cells for the appropriate scaling (and if you want more precise full and empty values).

Comment: could you suggest a "low-leakage op amp" model? Please?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/product/tlv2450

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single cell, then the [Fuel gauge](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10617) from Sparkfun would be great. Instead of reading analog values manually it sends the battery level via I2C.

Comment: "(so using an external battery charge meter IC is cheating :P)" - no can do, sir, also two cells in series.